# sticky navigation bar issues

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am very new to html and CSS. I made a prototype webpage, and things were working fine. I thought it would be a good idea to make the horizontal top navigation bar sticky.

At first, it wasn't working. I basically made it only sticky if you added the `nav` class. I first did this using `div`, and it didn't work. I fixed it by changing it to `span`. For some reason that worked, but it didn't work for the whole page.

Basically, the navigation bar is behind one of the sections, but not the others.

I heard about using `z-index`, but they said that that only works for `div`. `z-index` also need you to use `position: relative`, but I am using `position: sticky`. I may be wrong about `z-index` or am missing something.

So, how do I make the navigation bar sticky, be in front of the left column and the body, but not the right column.

---

html: (sorry if it is poorly formatted)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>My first web page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<span class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
<div class="left-column">
  <div class="body">
<h1>My first web page</h1>

<h2>What this is</h2>
<p>A simple page put together using HTML. <em>I said a simple page put together using HTML.</em> A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML. A simple page put together using HTML.</p>

<h2>Why this is</h2>
<ul>
    <li>To learn HTML</li>
    <li>To show off
        <ol>
            <li>To my boss</li>
            <li>To my friends</li>
            <li>To my cat</li>
            <li>To the little talking duck in my brain</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Because I have fallen in love with my computer and want to give her some HTML loving.</li>
</ul>

<h2>Where to find the <a href = "http://www.htmldog.com">tutorial</a></h2>
<p><a href="http://www.htmldog.com"><img src="http://www.htmldog.com/badge1.gif" width="120" height="90" alt="HTML Dog"></a></p>

<h3>Some random table</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 3, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>This web site is about <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> and <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>.</p>

<p>If you add the line <code><var>givevaderachuckle</var> = true;</code> to the <code>destroy_planet</code> subroutine and then type <kbd>ilovejabba</kbd> into the console, the big bad green Death Star laser will etch <samp>Slug Lover!</samp> on the planet's surface.
alsfo  jfdjs ioj iojo ijio jioj oijoi joisodfil givevaderachuckle jksldfk;afjskdfl</p>

<code><pre>
&lt;div id="intro"&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;Some heading&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Some paragraph paragraph thing thing thingy.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre></code>

<h3>Some random form</h3>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> It looks the part, but won't do a damned thing.</p>

<form action="somescript.php" method="post">

<p>Name:</p>
<p><input name="name" value="Your name"></p>

<p>Comments: </p>
<p><textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="comments">Your comments</textarea></p>

<p>Are you:</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="areyou" value="male"> Male</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="areyou" value="female"> Female</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="areyou" value="hermaphrodite"> An hermaphrodite</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="areyou" value="asexual" checked> Asexual</p>

<p><input type="submit"></p>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 500px;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #6393BC;
  padding: 0;
}
.left-column {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 200px;
  border-left: solid;
  border-color: #6393BC;
}
.body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 100px 100px;
}




h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 30px;
}




p {
  padding: 0px 60px;
}
p:not(.un-indent) { text-indent: 40px; }  .un-indent { text-indent: 0px; }




a {
  color: #6393BC;
}




ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 75px;
}
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 75px;
}





code {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color #dfdfdf;
}
code pre {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0px 60px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  border-left: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-color: #6393BC;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.new-code {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}




.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-color: #6393BC;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /*Safari*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #bbb;
}
.nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 40px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.nav ul li a:hover.active {
  background-color: #6393BC;
}
.nav .active {
  background-color: #6EA2D0;
}
```

Also, sorry if there are jokes or links to my tutorial in there, it was part of the what the website told me to do.

How it is supposed to be layered: (imagine it was sticky, and midway in the page)
[image: what it is supposed to look like]
What it looks like:
[image: What it looks like]

How can I achieve a sticky navigation bar that is properly layered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set z-index of ul element to 1.
This works fine.